# Use SpriteKit update func as animation loop for SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, sprite-kit

Can I use the update function in a SKScene class to animate a view in SwiftUI?
In a project I use something like this:

```
class X: SKScene, ObservableObject{       
     @Published var x: CGFloat = 30
     //...
}

struct ContentView: View{
    @ObservedObject var scene = X()

    var body: some View{
         ZStack{
              SpriteView(scene: scene)
              Circle().frame(width: scene.l, height: scene.l)
         }
    }
}
```

When the update function is called, then the property "x" can be changed and then the Circle should change too. In the other project I saw that there is a growing memory usage over time. I don't know why this is happening. Perhaps there is somebody who has an idea.

Comment: I'm sure you *could* do it that way, but I'd recommend looking into `CADisplayLink`, as seen here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cadisplaylink

Comment: I used this too but I need to have many objects where only one is added and one removed each frame and with SpriteKit this is good possible. So should I use then only SpriteKit?